# Android NullPointerException on WebView goBack() method

Tags: java, android, webview, nullpointerexception

I am using Google Analytics for my android applications and see NullPointerException on the line "wvBrowser.goBack();" although I check it before if the wvBrowser(WebView) is null. I can't make it happen on my normal tests. Any idea?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
           if (wvBrowser!=null) {
                if(wvBrowser.canGoBack() == true){
                    wvBrowser.goBack();
                    return true;
                }else{
                }
           }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the crash

Comment: Cannot produce the bug myself. Analytics do not give stacktrace...

Comment: I got the stacktrace by some modifications to analytics:
Thread: main, Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.webkit.WebView.goBackOrForward(WebView.java:1812) at android.webkit.WebView.goBackOrForward(WebView.java:1806) at android.webkit.WebView.goBack(WebView.java:1755) at com.xxx.NewsBrowserActivity.onKeyDown(NewsBrowserActivity.java:180) at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1390) at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2137)